# Change elements of one specific div of *ngFor

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have this [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxB3O.png). What I want to do is, when a button `Join` is clicked, hide that button and show an input field in its place [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVMJO.png), and if another button is clicked the first one returns to its normal state and another input field is displayed [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeCN7.png).

I'm working with Angular 13. Here is a code snippet of the concerned div.

```
<div *ngIf='show === "default"' class="list">
  <div class="form-listItem" *ngFor="let room of roomList">
    {{ room }}
    <button class="formBtn" (click)="enterPassword($event.target)" id="{{ room }}">Join</button>
    <div class="joinRoomPasswordContainer" id="{{ room }}-">
      <input class="joinRoomPassword" type="password" placeholder="********">
      <button class="joinRoomBtn">
        <img class="rightArrow" src="/assets/rightArrow.svg" alt="">
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add a property for room object, some like 'joined', then add ngIf directive for view change

```
<button class="formBtn" *ngIf="!room.joined" (click)="enterPassword($event.target); room.joined = true" id="{{ room 
}}">Join</button>
<div class="joinRoomPasswordContainer" id="{{ room }}-" *ngIf="room.joined">
  <input class="joinRoomPassword" type="password" placeholder="********">
  <button class="joinRoomBtn">
    <img class="rightArrow" src="/assets/rightArrow.svg" alt="">
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is just the thing I needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
 In the Ts file you initialize two variable with boolean type true and false.
and create write a fun like:-
func1(){
this.a = true;
this.b = false;
}
```

call this function on the button and the panel you want to open on click that div give - *ngIf  with these two variable.